# SAS -Make one proc univariate table instead of two for same variable with different where clause

Tags: sas

[image]The code is commented out at the moment but it produces two tables... how can I make it one table to compare the where clause from the same variable since you can't put more than one where clause for an additional row? I'm also trying to make a pie chart so if I figure this out I can knock out two birds with one.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `where` clauses select mutually exclusive row sets (there is no row that can meet both where criteria) you can create a synthetic class variable.

In the data preparation

```
  length med_case $10;
  select;
    when mager <= 50 and meduc = 4 then med_case = 'case 1';
    when mager <= 50 and meduc < 4 then med_case = 'case 2';
    otherwise med_case= 'ignore';
  end;
```

and in univariate

```
  where med_case in ('case 1', 'case 2');
  class med_case;
```